# Return filtered LIKE results in SQLite using FMDB

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

Using SQLite is there a way of using the LIKE command where the search parameter could find results that would be considered a substring of itself

ie. a search parameter of "delicious and tasty fruit and cinnamon." could return "delicious and tasty" in a DESC order by length so that if delicious was also a returned result it would show up last.

searching for "delicious and tasty fruit and cinnamon." could return...

```
 delicious and tasty fruit
 delicious and tasty
 delicious
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you state what you want to search for in one succinct English sentence?

Comment: What I hoping for is that there is a SQLite LIKE statement that can take in "delicious and testy fruit and cinnamon" and return "delicious and tasty"

Comment: Still not clear. How can "testy" find something with "tasty"? Please amend your question (rather than answering in a commend) with a sentence like: "Find all occurrences of the phrase A in the DefinitionText field of Definitions satisfying the following conditions...". Also, please post your iteration code that you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need LIKE for that:

```
SELECT * FROM [foo]
WHERE a = substr('delicious and tasty fruit and cinnamona', 1, length(a))
ORDER BY length(a) DESC
```

Comment: Is there any way to detect a substring in the middle of a field? not just at the beginning? 
    SELECT * FROM [Definitions]
    WHERE DefinitionText = substr('I love you off the hook but shouldnt you be off to work?', 12, length(DefinitionText))
    ORDER BY length(DefinitionText) DESC
detects "off to work" but only after I changed the starting index to 12, when the starting index is 1 it won't catch it.

Comment: instr(X,Y): finds the first occurrence of string Y within string X and returns the number of prior characters plus 1, or 0 if Y is nowhere found within X.